# How to display database records in the view without repeating a field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

In my database I have two tables one politics (politics_id, politics, politics_type_id) and other tipo_politics (politics_type_id,  politics_type).
This is the table **politics**

```
politics_id | politics    | politics_type_id
--------    | --------    | -------------
1           | Politic 1   | 1
2           | hello world | 2
3           | magic       | 1
4           | love        |1
```

This is the table **tipo_politics**

```
 politics_type_id | politics_type
  -------------    | --------
  1                | general
  2                | life
```

What I need is in the view to show the records of the politics table with the type of politics as the header, but the header is not repeated. Something like this.

```
**General**
- Politic 1
- magic
- love

**Life**
- hello world
```

I trate to do the query with a group by but only shows one record with politics_type_id **1**. This is the view code.

```
 <?php
   for ($j = 0; $j < $contador; $j++) {
 ?>
   <div class="content-layout">
         <p>
           <span>
                <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politics_type']; ?> 
           </span> 
         </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul style="text-indent: 0px;">
         <li>
             <span>
                   <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politics']; ?>   
             </span>
         </li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
 <?php } // for j ?>
```

With this form show the records like this:

```
 **General**
    - Politic 1
 **General**
    - magic
 **General**
    - love

  **Life**
    - hello world
```

I hope you can help me and that my question be a good question.

Comment: You need an inner loop that loops through the politics, within the outer loop that loops through the types.

Comment: when i put a loop o for in the span that shows the politics this only make that the text be repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the headers to be displayed only when there's a change in `politics_type`. This would require keeping a track of its value in every iteration and the logic can thus be constructed as follows:

```
<?php
$previous_politics_type = "";
for ($j = 0; $j < $contador; $j++) {
    if($previous_politics_type != $list_politic[$j]['politics_type']){  // <-- new if condition
?>

        <div class="content-layout">
            <p>
                <span>
                    <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politics_type']; ?> 
                </span> 
            </p>
        </div>
<?php
    }       // <-- end if
    $previous_politics_type = $list_politic[$j]['politics_type'];
?> 
    <div>
        <ul style="text-indent: 0px;">
            <li>
                <span>
                    <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politicas']; ?>   
                </span>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php 
} // for j 
?>
```

The layout of the `<div>`s above may or may not be exactly as you need, but hopefully it should give an idea on how to use the new `$previous_politics_type` variable.

Comment: i have a question, where is the variable $politics_type ?? i have tu iniyialize? or its  a mistake and its the $previous_politics_type variable. If this is the case it works but stiil the same header its repeat

Comment: sorry, and THANKS!!! it works with the change of $politics_type for $previous_politics_type, i have a where in the model with comments.

Comment: Sorry, there was a slight mistake in the second usage of that variable, which I've now corrected. Thanks for pointing that out and am glad that it worked for you.

Comment: Doesn't this give a whole new `<ul>` for each politicas, instead of a single `<ul>` with each politicas in a `<li>`?

Comment: No, that give me a <div> for each políticas, its not the perfect design but works what i want, it's just adjust issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a query like this, then you'll get a row for the type as well as the actual politics:

```
select tp.politics_type_id, tp.politics_type politics_text, null politics_id,  1 row_type
from tipo_politics tp
union
select p.politics_type_id, p.politics politics_text, p.politics_id, 2 row_type
from politics p
order by politics_type_id, row_type, politics_id;
```

This gives results like this:

```
+------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
| politics_type_id | politics_text | politics_id | row_type |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
|                1 | general       |             |        1 |
|                1 | Politic 1     |           1 |        2 |
|                1 | magic         |           3 |        2 |
|                1 | love          |           4 |        2 |
|                2 | life          |             |        1 |
|                2 | hello world   |           2 |        2 |
+------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

Now you can loop through the results, and only act on the header rows (where `row_type = 1`).  Then within that loop, do another loop and pick out the detail rows (where `row_type = 2`).

```
<?php
   for ($j = 0; $j < $contador; $j++) {
     if($list_politic[$j]['row_type'] == 1){
 ?>
   <div class="content-layout">
         <p>
           <span>
                <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politics_text']; ?> 
           </span> 
         </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul style="text-indent: 0px;">
         <li>
          <?php for($i=0; $i < $contador; $i++) {
                if($list_politic[$i]['row_type'] == 2 && $list_politic[$i]['politics_type_id'] == $list_politic[$j]['politics_type_id']) {
          ?>
             <span>
                   <?php echo $list_politic[$j]['politics_text']; ?>   
             </span>
            <?php } // if ?>
           <?php } // for i ?>
         </li> 
       </ul>
    </div>
   <?php } // for if ?>
 <?php } // for j ?>
```