# how make a loop for inside another loop for without repeat values in a bidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, for-loop, view

I have a query in my controller, in which i search data according an id, it return 2 results, then I want search some datas according with the previously result and them shows in a view. Its something like this:

- first query:

  ```
  $query_1 = $obj1->Searcher_Test($type);

  function Searcher_Test($type) 
      {
        $this->db->join('n_type', 'n_type.id_test = test.id_test');
        $this->db->where('test.id_type', $type);
        return $this->db->get('test');
       }
  ```
- second query:

  ```
  $query_2 = $obj2->Searcher_charact($id_test);<br> 
    function Searcher_charact($id_test) <br> 
          {<br> 
            $this->db->join('charact', 'charact.id_test = test.id_test');<br> 
            $this->db->where('test.id_test', $id_test);<br> 
            return $this->db->get('test');<br> 
           }<br>
  ```
- the first query give me 2 results

  ```
       id_test | test  |id_type
       ------- |------ |--------
         1     | one   |   1
         2     | two   |   1
  ```
- the second query give me 3 results

  ```
      id_charact | charact | id_test
          1      |  moduls |    1
          2      |  direct |    1
          3      |  integer|    2
  ```

I make this for loop

```
$contador = 0;
$list_test = array(array());
$contador_charact = 0;
$list_charact = array(array());

for ($i = 0; $i < $query_1->num_rows; $i++) { 
     $id_test = $query_1->row($i)->id_test;   
     $query_2 = $obj2->Searcher_charact($id_test); 

     for ($j = 0; $j < $query_2->num_rows; $j++) {
        $list_charact[$contador_charact]['charact'] = $query_2->row($j)->charact;
        $contador_charact ++;
     }// for j

     $list_test[$contador]['test'] = $query_1->row($j)->test;

     $contador++;

}// for i
```

and in the view I make this, but it shows me all the records, including the id_test = 1 and id_test = 2

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) {
<div class="layout-item-0">
<?php echo $list_test[$i]['test']; ?>
   for ($j = 0; $j < $contador_charact; $j++) {
?>
   <li>
     <?php echo $list_charact[$j]['charact']?>
   </li>
<?php
     } //for j
</div>
} //for i
```

it shows something like this:

```
one
   moduls
   directs
   integer

two
   moduls
   directs
   integer
```

and I want that shows

```
one
   moduls
   directs
   integer

two
   integer
```

I do not know if my query its wrong, my loop for or my view. Please help, thanks in adavance.

Comment: thanks for editing my question, I do not know why some parts I can't editied

Comment: Looking at the data, perhaps `integer` shouldn't be shown with `one`?

Comment: no, is not sopoused that integer shows with one, it should be with to, like I show at the end of my question

Comment: Hola Mary. Why you undo the changes I did to your format? You need add 4 spaces after a bullet point so appear in `code format`

Comment: sorry, mabe i did this trying format the part of the view, please help me to format the question, i don't know why I can't format some parts of my question

Comment: could you format the part of the view??

Comment: If you're using `JOIN`, you don't need loop inside a loop.  The only query needed should be: `SELECT c.id_charact, c.charact, c.id_test, t.test   FROM charact c     INNER JOIN test t     ON c.id_test = t.id_test    WHERE t.id_type = ?` (please substitute question mark with your value). The rest of the issue (with regards to the loop and iterations) is then similar to one your previous [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43615827/2298301)

Comment: I tried to do what you taught me but do not work. A loop inside a loop is because i find an id_type, and then I find the characteristics

Comment: In your loop, where does `$id_test` get set in `$query_2 = $obj2->Searcher_charact($id_test);` ??

Comment: in the loop after for(i), i forgett put it in, sorry

Comment: Can you show us your db schema, sample data and sql query. And explain the logic of your output. Because In your sample `Id = 1` doesn't have integer

Comment: no, i have not, that's the problem, I want to show the datas like the example at the end of my question

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. I find my answer, I do this in my view:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++) {
        <div class="layout-item-0">
          <?php echo $list_test[$i]['test']; ?>
             for ($j = 0; $j < $contador_charact; $j++) {
                 if ($id_test == $list_charact[$j]['id_test']) { // <--- this is what I add
               ?>
        <li>
        <?php echo $list_charact[$j]['charact']?>
        </li>
        <?php
                  }//del if                 
              } //for j
        </div>
        } //for i
```