# group array values and loop through

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a MySQL table which stored data which are relevant for a certain year

Table name: `registrations`

```
id   name     year     address    
1    Tom      2011     NY   
2    Peter    2012     NY   
3    harry    2011     NY   
4    Steve    2012     NY   
5    Tommy    2013     NY   
6    Steph    2013     NY   
7    Sean     2011     NY
```

i use the below query to get the data from the table

```
select * from registrations ORDER by year ASC
```

on my `PHP` code i use a `foreach` loop to iterate through the array values

the problem is that i want to show the records by year, for an example

```
year - 2011
       Name: Tom
       Address: NY

       Name: Harry
       Address: NY

       Name: Sean
       Address: NY

Year - 2012
       Name: Peter
       Address: NY

 ............
```

Can someone please tell me what would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You're already ordering by year. So, inside your loop, just add a check -- if the year of the current record is different than the year of the last record, then output a new year header section.

Comment: show us your php.

Comment: A closely related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43615073/2298301) as far as looping logic is concerned.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thanks... :) That solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This first step is getting all of your data grouped the way you wanted it to be grouped. `$records` variable simulates that which is returned by mysql. The loop at the end simply creates a new array with the year as the key and subarrays of the peoples information. This should make it really easy to loop through and print out the values you want in the format specified.

```
$records = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'year' => 2011,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Peter',
        'year' => 2012,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'harry',
        'year' => 2011,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Steve',
        'year' => 2012,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Tommy',
        'year' => 2013,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Steph',
        'year' => 2013,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'name' => 'Sean',
        'year' => 2011,
        'address' => 'NY'
    ],
];


$byYear = [];
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $year = $record['year'];
    $person = ['Name' => $record['name'], 'Address' => $record['address']];
    if (!isset($byYear[$year])) {
        $byYear[$year] = [];
    }
    array_push($byYear[$year], $person);
}
```